# Solr custom UpdateRequestProcessorFactory fails with "Error Instantiating UpdateRequestProcessorFactory"

Tags: java, solr, lucene, config, solrcloud

I have a custom class extending `UpdateRequestProcessorFactory` doing some work on a document when it gets added to the index. This was working fine in `v4.10.3` in standalone Solr. I moved to SolrCloud `v5.2` and it throws this error when adding the Collection (node):

```
ERROR - 2015-06-14 12:25:11.071; [   docs_shard1_replica1] org.apache.solr.common.SolrException; org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'docs_shard1_replica1': Unable to create core [docs_shard1_replica1] Caused by: class com.example.solr.update.processor.SelfTaggerUpdateProcessorFactory
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleCreateAction(CoreAdminHandler.java:661)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleRequestInternal(CoreAdminHandler.java:213)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleRequestBody(CoreAdminHandler.java:193)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:143)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdminRequest(HttpSolrCall.java:646)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:417)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:227)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [docs_shard1_replica1]
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:651)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:611)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleCreateAction(CoreAdminHandler.java:628)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error Instantiating UpdateRequestProcessorFactory, com.example.solr.update.processor.SelfTaggerUpdateProcessorFactory failed to instantiate org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessorFactory
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:815)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:658)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:637)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error Instantiating UpdateRequestProcessorFactory, com.example.solr.update.processor.SelfTaggerUpdateProcessorFactory failed to instantiate org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessorFactory
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:587)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInitInstance(SolrCore.java:622)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initPlugins(SolrCore.java:2281)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessorChain.init(UpdateRequestProcessorChain.java:126)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInitInstance(SolrCore.java:624)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initPlugins(SolrCore.java:2265)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initPlugins(SolrCore.java:2259)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.loadUpdateProcessorChains(SolrCore.java:1069)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:766)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.example.solr.update.processor.SelfTaggerUpdateProcessorFactory
    at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:3208)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:475)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:422)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:566)
    ... 39 more
```

In solrconfig.xml I have configured like this:

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain>
     <processor class="com.example.solr.update.processor.SelfTaggerUpdateProcessorFactory" lib="custom-libs" version="1">
        <arr name="source">
            <str>title</str>
            <str>desc</str>
            <str>subject</str>
            <str>content</str>
        </arr>
        <str name="dest">category</str>
     </processor>
     ...
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

I have tried to add my custom jar in two ways:

1. Add it to the `server/lib/` folder where all the `Jetty` jars are located. This fails with `Error Instantiating UpdateRequestProcessorFactory`
2. Add it to the `.system` collection as suggested and then make it available to the `<processor />` using the `lib` and `version` attributes, which fails with a `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.solr.update.processor.SelfTaggerUpdateProcessorFactory`

Does this `Error Instantiating UpdateRequestProcessorFactory` exception tell something I don't see? Does the move from standalone to Solrcloud require something for my custom code I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is a `classloader` issue. I had added my custom jar into the `server/lib/` folder.

When I added the `Collection`, it would instantiate my custom class which needs the `UpdateRequestProcessorFactory` class but is not available in that `classloader`.

I solved this by rmoving my jar from `server/lib/` and adding this line to `solrconfig.xml`:

```
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../..}/custom-libs/" regex="solr-.*\.jar" />
```

and putting my custom jar in a `custom-libs/` folder in `${SOLR_HOME}`. This way I make sure that my custom classes are only loaded when the `Collection` is added, and not before, so they are in the correct `classloader`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is moving from standalone Solr to a Cloud one. Specifically, about where you store your jar file with the custom component. It is probably not visible to all the nodes and therefore fails.

However, Solr 5.2 does have new functionality related to that you may want to use. It allows to [use the Config API to add the library](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Adding+Custom+Plugins+in+SolrCloud+Mode), assuming you enable that functionality.

Comment: I tried what you said, simplifying the scenario to a 1 node cloud. I removed the custom jar from the node's lib folder, crated the .system collection, uploaded the custom jar, which I can list OK. I added the "lib" and "version" attributes to my solrconfig.xml. I restarted Solrcloud, add the collection and now the error is Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.solr.update.processor.SelfTaggerUpdateProcessorFactory

Comment: Did you use -Denable.runtime.lib=true ?
Also, the original issue may also be indicated that the interface is not matching the parent (ClassCastException). There may have been some constructor changes in between. I would check the source example in 5.2 matching whatever you were using as an example in an earlier version.

Comment: I think I found the answer, related to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8728829/1412531